# Ext.List shows only 1 value instead of all

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

im using a AJAX request to get value from the server in a JSON format.
but when i try to show this in the Ext.List only 1 value shows up instead of all.

```
Ext.setup({
onReady: function() {

    Ext.regModel('Contact', {
        fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
    });
            var posts;
            var count;
            var name = 'sdf';
      Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'a.php/pool/listPools',
                    method: 'post',
                    type:'json',
                    success: function(response){
                          posts = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                          alert(response.responseText);
                          count = posts.count;
                          for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                          name = posts.data[i].name;
                          alert(name);
                          var btnContact = new Ext.TabPanel({
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [ new Ext.List({
                            itemTpl:'',
            title: 'My Tab',
            tpl: '<tpl for="."><div class="contact"><strong>{firstName}</strong> {lastName}</div></tpl>',
            itemSelector: 'div.contact',
            singleSelect: true,
            grouped: true,
            indexBar: false,


            store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                model: 'Contact',
                sorters: 'firstName',

                getGroupString: function (record) {
                  return record.get('firstName');
                },
                data:  [
                    {
                                                firstName: name,
                                                lastName: ''
                                            }
                ]
            })
        }), 
                     //{ title: 'Tab 2' } 
                ]   
                    });

                }}               
            });

}
```

});

Sooo my question is, how can i show all the retrieved data? instead of just 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your TabPanel inside the for loop which is creating one TabPanel per array item with each TabPanel having a List bound to a store with a single record. These are all on top of each other so you are only seeing one at a time.

To get this working quickly, I would take your TabPanel creation outside the for loop and build your data set within it:

```
var dataArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   name = posts.data[i].name;

   dataArray.push({
                   firstName: name,
                   lastName: ''
              });
}
```

You can then pass this dataArray to your store:

```
new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            model: 'Contact',
            sorters: 'firstName',

            getGroupString: function (record) {
              return record.get('firstName');
            },
            data:  dataArray
        })
```

I would suggest however that you look into how to make your stores load this data themselves (via proxies) as this is the best way to do it.

Stuart